# Eagerly fetch child when loading parent spring data jpa

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

Link.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LINK")
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="LINK_ID"))
public class Link extends AbstractAuditableEntity<Integer> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3825555385014396995L;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="UI_SREF")
    private String uiSref;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_LINK_ID")
    private Link parentLink;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentLink", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Link> childLinks;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the uiSref
     */
    public String getUiSref() {
        return uiSref;
    }

    /**
     * @param uiSref the uiSref to set
     */
    public void setUiSref(String uiSref) {
        this.uiSref = uiSref;
    }

    /**
     * @return the parentLink
     */
    public Link getParentLink() {
        return parentLink;
    }

    /**
     * @param parentLink the parentLink to set
     */
    public void setParentLink(Link parentLink) {
        this.parentLink = parentLink;
    }

    /**
     * @return the childLinks
     */
    public List<Link> getChildLinks() {
        return childLinks;
    }

    /**
     * @param childLinks the childLinks to set
     */
    public void setChildLinks(List<Link> childLinks) {
        this.childLinks = childLinks;
    }


}
```

LinkRepository .java

```
public interface LinkRepository extends BaseRepository<Integer, Link> {

    @Query("select distinct p from Link l JOIN fetch l.parentLink p where l.id in (select lar.link.id from LinkAccessRole lar where lar.accessRoleLu in ?1) and p.id in (select lar.link.id from LinkAccessRole lar where lar.accessRoleLu in ?1)")
    public List<Link> getNavigationByaccessRoleLuList(List<AccessRoleLu> accessRoleLu);
}
```

[Link_Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjkMr.png) 
[Link_Access_Role Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8dH3.png)

generated Queries:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT t0.LINK_ID, t0.CREATED_BY_ID, t0.CREATED_DATE, t0.LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID, t0.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, t0.NAME, t0.UI_SREF, t0.PARENT_LINK_ID FROM LINK t0, LINK t1 WHERE ((t1.LINK_ID IN (SELECT t2.LINK_ID FROM LINK_ACCESS_ROLE t3, LINK t2 WHERE ((t3.ACCESS_ROLE_ID IN (?,?)) AND (t2.LINK_ID = t3.LINK_ID))) AND t0.LINK_ID IN (SELECT t4.LINK_ID FROM LINK_ACCESS_ROLE t5, LINK t4 WHERE ((t5.ACCESS_ROLE_ID IN (?,?)) AND (t4.LINK_ID = t5.LINK_ID)))) AND (t0.LINK_ID = t1.PARENT_LINK_ID))
        bind => [4 parameters bound]
    SELECT LINK_ID, CREATED_BY_ID, CREATED_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, NAME, UI_SREF, PARENT_LINK_ID FROM LINK WHERE (PARENT_LINK_ID = ?)
        bind => [1 parameter bound]
    SELECT LINK_ID, CREATED_BY_ID, CREATED_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, NAME, UI_SREF, PARENT_LINK_ID FROM LINK WHERE (PARENT_LINK_ID = ?)
        bind => [1 parameter bound]
```

I get one query for each child related to the fetched parent Regardless it has the access role or not.

i want to fetch the parents and its childs that have access role not all childs that related to that parent.

Comment: You have fetch = FetchType.EAGER. What do you think it is for? It tells JPA that every time a link is loaded, its children must be loaded.

Comment: That's right. how can i fetch them based on their access role as i  was trying to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that you can fetch a parent entity and have one of its collections populated with a subset of entries based on some *criteria* is by using Hibernate's proprietary filters.

I'm not certain whether the other JPA providers provide some proprietary solution either, but JPA itself doesn't offer this directly.

You first need to register a filter definition using `@FilterDef` and then you need to reference the filter's definition using the `@Filter` on your collection property.

The hard part here is that you can't rely on Spring data's `@Query` or their repository implementation generation process to help.  You will need to use a real implementation so that you can manually enable this hibernate filter *before* you query the parent entity.

```
Filter filter = session.enableFilter( "link-with-restrictions-by-roles" );
filter.setParameter( "roles", yourRolesList );
return session.createQuery( ... ).getResultList();
```

The documentation describes the use of `@Filter` and `@FilterDef` in detail.  You can also find another post of mine where I give slightly more implementation details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451985/1572269).